# Which would be better for the syntax for an array?

Tags: syntax, command

I am making a scripting language, but I need help on deciding some syntax. I am mainly having issues deciding two things.

First, the syntax for calling an parts in the array. I was thinking one of two options, but give me suggestions if you want.

Let's say I have an array that in Javascript would be represented as

```
var people = [
    ["Joe",34],
    ["Bill",29],
    ["Steve",36]
];
```

The options are

```
Option One
    people[2][1]
    returns 36

Option Two
    people[2,1]
    returns 36
```

Second, the syntax for calling a function. I was thinking one of two options, but give me suggestions if you want.

Let's say I have a function that in Javascript would be represented as

```
function foo(bar,hi) {
    return bar;
}
```

The options are

```
Option One
    The same as Javascript

    example:
    function foo(bar,hi) {
        return bar
    }

Option Two
    The same as Javascript, but
    - separating each private variable with it's own set of parentheses
    - no need to state "function" in front

    example:
    foo(bar)(hi){
        return bar
    }

Option Three
    The same as Javascript, but
    - a colon to separate the namespace from the private variables
    - no parentheses due to the lack of need

    example:
    foo:bar,hi{
        return bar
    }
```

Any and all advice and suggestions would be very helpful! I hope you guys come up with some great ideas for way to do this, and please suggest anything for syntax. I still need help with some other things, but those are not really any big decisions.

***Thanks in advance!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The decision is not one of syntax - you are deciding whether to include 2D arrays as a base type. If your goal is to write a simple language, this is definitely overkill. Nested arrays are good enough (people[2][1]).

2) Since you're going to have to parse for these function patterns yourself (and from what I gather you don't have access to regular expressions), you should choose based on ease of parsing. To me, that's clearly option #1, because you have a definite start point for any declaration of a function (the reserved word "function"). When you are parsing through the script, if your token buffer consists of only "function", you know the following bit of code is going to be a function declaration.  The same cannot be said for either of your other proposals.